# Having trouble getting a vertical scroll bar in a child div

Tags: css, overflow

I want and can't get a scroll bar to appear in the box-content div. Adding 'overflow-y:auto' doesn't work.

My requirements:

- The entire layout must adjust to the browser height. That's why I
  have #wrap { ... height: 50vh; ...}
- The scroll bar must not include
  the header. It must only apply to the box-content div.  I want the height of the header to adjust to the contents and wrap them if necessary.

Here's the css

```
    #wrap { 
        margin: 10px;
        height: 50vh;
        border: 2px solid black;
    }

    .container {
        border: 4px solid red;
        padding: 4px 3px;
        margin: 0;
        max-height: 90%;        /* As a percentage of the parent. */ 
        /* height: 300px;       /* This causes the scroll bar to appear, but its not what I want. */
    }   

    .box-header {
        background-color: green;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        color: white;
    }

    .box-content {
        border: 3px solid blue;
        overflow:auto;
        padding: 5px;
        padding-top: 10px;
        max-height:100%;
    }
```

And the HTML

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="box-header"> Header String</div>
        <div class="box-content">
             <p>line 1</p>
             <p>line 2</p>
             <p>line 3</p>
             <p>line 4</p>
             <p>line 5</p>
             <p>line 6</p>
             <p>line 7</p>
             <p>line 8</p>
             <p>line 9</p>
             <p>line 10</p>
             <p>line 11</p>
             <p>line 12</p>
             <p>line 13</p>
             <p>line 14</p>
             <p>line 15</p>          
             <p>line 16</p>
             <p>line 17</p>
             <p>line 18</p>
             <p>line 19</p>          
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Here's a link to a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mjvancouver905/5vswprfw/

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `flex` layout

```css
#wrap {
  margin: 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.container {
  padding: 4px 3px;
  margin: 0;
  height: 50vh;
  /* As a percentage of the parent. */
  /* height: 300px;    /* This causes the scroll bar to appear, but can't be used because the height must adjust to the size of the screen. */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.box-header {
  background-color: green;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  color: white;
}

.box-content {
  border: 3px solid blue;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div class="container" style="border: 4px solid red">
    <div class="box-header"> Header in the B1 div.</div>
    <div class="box-content">
      <p>line 1</p>
      <p>line 2</p>
      <p>line 3</p>
      <p>line 4</p>
      <p>line 5</p>
      <p>line 6</p>
      <p>line 7</p>
      <p>line 8</p>
      <p>line 9</p>
      <p>line 10</p>
      <p>line 11</p>
      <p>line 12</p>
      <p>line 13</p>
      <p>line 14</p>
      <p>line 15</p>
      <p>line 16</p>
      <p>line 17</p>
      <p>line 18</p>
      <p>line 19</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That works!  It worked when I changed the browser window size and it also worked when the header text was on more than one line.

Comment: @user3341576 awesome, flex is really great at layouts like this.

Answer (score 0):

You should add  a proper (fixed  max-heigth)  eg:

```
.box-content {
  border: 3px solid blue;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  max-height: 400px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/motka53y/

Comment: This didn't work for me.  Adjust your browser window and you'll see that the content div extends past the container for some sizes.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way. First of all your container should have a fixed width so that any overflow can be hidden. so you'd have to change max-height : 90% to height: 90%. then you'd have to add the property overflow-hidden so that the overflown part outside the container is hidden.

Here's a working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/5vswprfw/12/

This is what i changed in the css styles :

```
  .container {
  padding: 4px 3px;
  margin: 0;
  height: 90%;
  overflow:hidden;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, but the box-content extends below the container and is hidden.

Comment: Again this didn't work for me, and to see why, you may have to adjust your browser window size.  I found the content extending below the bottom of the container.

Comment: if you set overflow:hidden for The div with the id wrap the container doesnt extend past it.  https://jsfiddle.net/5vswprfw/16/

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work for me either.  I'm using Chrome.  What are you using? The scroll bar is there, but the down arrow on the scroll bar is hidden to me. Its below the container.